# How do ControlCollection.Item(s) work?

Tags: c#, time-complexity, controlcollection

Sorry for bad English.

I need to create and manage a large (not that "large"!) number of controls, through the code. I know how to create them and link the events. The issue is the way of future access to added controls.

Which property works better? ControlCollection.Item[int index] or ControlCollection.Item[string key]?

I think that the time complexity of Item[int] must be O(1), and time complexity of Item[string] must be O(n). Is it right?

Comment: It could be O(1) by using a hashtable, but it doesn't.

Comment: So, you are saying that both are O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

`ControlCollection.this[string]` is O(n), except that it caches the most-recently-looked-up name.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the final answer? Considering all aspects, which one is the **best**?

Comment: They do two different things.  If you have an index, `this[int]` is obviously better.

Comment: That's like asking "Which is best? A `List<string>` or a `Dictionary<string, string>`?"

Comment: I meant the least access time by "which is best?". Anyway... Thanks man.